# Ubuntu does not repond to mouse clicks and freezes

Tags: dual-boot, mouse, desktop-environments

I have an Acer Nitro 5 AN515-52-54GU with i5 8300H, 8GB RAM, Nvidia 1050TI and 1TB HDD with 16GB IntelOptane

I turned off secureboot,

disabled the optane memory so that it functions as two different storage devices,

flashed Ubuntu 18.04 using Rufus with GPT partition scheme,

then livebooted Ubuntu but when I try to click on anything topbar, sidebar with applications, applications menu, right click on deshtop,

It does not respond at all, only mouse movement works, It sort of just freezes,
I am not even able to get to TTY using Crtl+Alt+F1,

When I try Xubuntu and Kali-XFCE it works fine for sometime until freezing when trying to open display settings

I have tried different mouses, same result.

What could be the problem and how do I fix it?

Comment: I'd check for BIOS or SSD firmware updates. See https://www.acer.com/ac/en/US/content/support-product/7572?b=1

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it by adding ' nomodeset ' in grub when booting,
Installed Ubuntu and Nvidia drivers,
Rebooted

Works properly now.